# Java generic map

Tags: java, generics

How can I define a map like this in Java?

```
Map<Class<T extends myObject>, MyObjectConverter<T>>
```

The problem is the `T` in both arguments. `T`  should be different for each map entry. But I want the map to be restricted to key-value-pairs that "share a common T"

The following definition works, but I think there must be a better way - without CompilerWarnings:

```
Map<Class<? extends myObject>, MyObjectConverter>
```

Comment: What is `T`? Where is it declared?

Comment: Thats the point: T should be different for each map entry. But I want the map to be restricted to key-value-pairs that "share a common T"

Comment: Wait a second.  You want `T` to be different for each entry?

Comment: This is impossible.  Sorry.

Comment: _"T should be different for each map entry. But I want the map to be restricted to key-value-pairs that "share a common T"_ - What you've described and what you've hacked with code that results in warnings isn't quite in sync. You said you want `T` to be different for each key-value, but you want those `T`'s to share a common superclass (eg: `E`). Is the superclass of `T` an actual concrete class, or is that supposed to be variable as well?

Comment: The common superclass is fixed. Here: `myObject`.

Comment: *`T` should be different for each map entry.* What you have in mind might be completely against the basic purpose of generics.

Comment: Not really, it would just be "T extends myObject"  previously it would have been a map of an interface or abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a class that implements a Map.

```
public class Cache<T> implements Map<... something ...> {
}
```

the main issue is that you need to clarify in your class declaration of T, not in the constraint of the Map interface.

```
public class Cache<T extends MyObject> implements Map<T, MyObjectConverter> {
  ...
}
```

Likewise (for methods and such) you need to clarify the generic "type" of T prior to using it in constraining parameters.

```
public <T extends MyObject> Collection<T> doFunc(T input, MyObjectConverter converter) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Technically, this wouldn't satisfy the constraints; if the OP desire to have a different `T` for each map entry, then this would still bind `T` to have an upper bound of some concrete class.

Comment: @Makoto - this would satisfy what he wants because he's asking how to set it up so that the type T is a sub-class of some concrete type (`MyObject`)